# execution of javascript functions in parallel in phonegap -cordova,

Tags: javascript, cordova

I use phonegap - cordova notification and phonegap statusBarNotification plugin.
I need run vibrate, beep and statusbarnotofication on one moment, how can i do this?

```
navigator.notification.vibrate(1000);
window.plugins.statusBarNotification.notify(data.title, data.message);    
navigator.notification.beep(1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I did this:

```
             window.plugins.statusBarNotification.notify("TITLE", "DATA");    
             navigator.notification.vibrate(1000);
             navigator.notification.beep(1);
```

It worked fine on an HTC Sensation phone running Android 2.3, and on Nexus 7 running Android 4.2. I could try with other devices if you need. One thing to note is that some devices don't have certain functionality...for example, the Nexus 7 doesn't have vibrate capability, so the code above will only show the Notification and make the beep noise. Also, make sure you have the volume turned up and a ring tone set.